# How to map data in react js on Radio button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, radio-button, mapping

Iam trying to display data in react js. Whenever user selects a radio button the data in the api should be displayed according to option selected by the user. i have mapped my radio button component. now i want it to display data according to selected option. the value coming rom the api is mapped below and i have commented on the section where i want to display my text.the parameter is reward_description which is to be mapped.

My code

```
<input
type="radio"
title="giftCard"
value={this.state.giftCard}
name={this.props.giftDetails.variations.map(
       (e) => e.reward_text 
     )}
   onChange={(e) => {
      this.setState({ giftCard: e.target.value });
       }}
                           
    onClick={() => {
      this.props.giftDetails.variations.map(
      (e) => this.setState({ giftDescription: e.reward_description })
            )
         }}
                            
 />
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: giftDescription}}/>
```

Ad api response is

```
"variations": [
          {
            "variation_id": 1,
            "variation_name": "210kr",
            "price": "210",
            "reward_text": "200kr. Price",
            "reward_description": "Med et gavekort til Sendentanke.dk kan du vælge mellem gavekort til hundredevis af butikker og oplevelser ét sted."
          },
          {
            "variation_id": 2,
            "variation_name": "400kro",
            "price": "400",
            "reward_text": "400 Price",
            "reward_description": "Earn a reward"
          }
        ],
```

Comment: RadioInputComponent is custom component ?

Comment: yes it is a custom component

Comment: Can u share a sample code sandbox ?

Comment: @SarunUK i have edited my question for better under standing

Comment: when ever this e.target.value is changed i want my reward description to be changed

Comment: I will check and let you know